# Imprimir quantidade de números pares em uma lista

Tags: python, python-3.x

Estou tentando fazer com que o código imprima apenas a quantidade de números pares que ele encontrar e não listar todos os números que ele achou.
O que estou tentando fazer com que apareça na tela:

```
5 números pares
```

O que está aparecendo na tela:

```
2

4

6

8

10
```

Estou usando este código para resolver o problema:

```py
for i in range(10):

    if(i%2==0):

        print(i, "Números pares!")
```

Testei alguns códigos porém ou acontecem erros ou o resultado é o mesmo.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ele imprime os números porque foi isso que você mandou fazer (colocou o `print` dentro do loop - o detalhe é que o seu código na verdade imprime os números 0, 2, 4, 6 e 8).

Se quer a quantidade, então crie um contador, atualize-o dentro do loop e só imprima no final:

```
qtd = 0
for i in range(10):
    if i % 2 == 0:
        qtd += 1

print(qtd, "números pares!")
```

Se quiser, também pode usar a sintaxe de [*list comprehension*](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html?highlight=list%20comprehension#list-comprehensions), bem mais sucinta e [*pythônica*](/q/192343/112052):

```
qtd = len([i for i in range(10) if i % 2 == 0])
```

Se estiver usando Python >= 3.6 é possível usar [*f-strings*](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#f-strings) para imprimir:

```
print(f"{qtd} números pares!")
```

---

Se bem que, para ter só os números pares, basta fazer o `range` pular de 2 em 2:

```
print(len(range(0, 10, 2)), "números pares!")
```

Outra opção, **para o caso específico** de só considerar os números pares entre zero e N (sendo N não-incluso), basta dividir N por 2 e arredondar para cima:

```
from math import ceil

# quantidade de números pares entre 0 e n (sendo n não-incluso)
def qtd_pares(n):
    return ceil(n / 2)

print(qtd_pares(10)) # 5 (pois o 10 não é incluso)
print(qtd_pares(11)) # 6 (pois o 10 agora é incluso)
```